# How to enable pretty logging of SOAP messages in JBoss 7

Tags: web-services, logging, soap, jboss, cxf

I have enabled SOAP logging by adding following in standalone.xml as described in [Jboss Advanced User Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/JBWS/Advanced+User+Guide#AdvancedUserGuide-Logging):

```
<system-properties>
  <property name="org.apache.cxf.logging.enabled" value="true"/>
</system-properties>
```

This configuration does not pretty print XML messages. I am sure that CXF supports pretty printing since there is a `AbstractLoggingInterceptor.setPrettyLogging()` method in the library.

How can I enable pretty printing of SOAP requests and responses in JBoss 7.

Comment: For additional pretty-printing features, see my lib https://github.com/greenbird/xml-formatter-components/tree/master/cxf

Comment: Any idea how to enable it on Websphere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using org.apache.cxf.logging.enabled property is the right way, it accepts value "pretty" for nicely formatted xml output

```
<system-properties>
  <property name="org.apache.cxf.logging.enabled" value="pretty"/>
</system-properties>
```

For details see https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/bus/extension/ExtensionManagerBus.java#L68-L72

Comment: At the time of posting this question, I had used that method and it didn't work(see my question). This is why I asked the question.

Answer (score 3):

Even though Serdal's answer is correct, it does not look practical to me.

**My solution**

I removed `org.apache.cxf.logging.enabled` system property and used following code to enable SOAP logging:

```
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);

LoggingInInterceptor inInterceptor = new LoggingInInterceptor();
inInterceptor.setPrettyLogging(true);
client.getInInterceptors().add(inInterceptor);

LoggingOutInterceptor outInterceptor = new LoggingOutInterceptor();
outInterceptor.setPrettyLogging(true);
client.getOutInterceptors().add(outInterceptor);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to pretty print and also to increase limit size of XML response from Webservice by doing the following:

```
        wsdlLocationURL = new URL(productServiceURLStr);
        ServiceFacadeBeanService serviceFacade =
                new ServiceFacadeBeanService(wsdlLocationURL,   SERVICE_FACADE_QNAME);
        ServiceFacade sfPort = serviceFacade.getServiceFacadeBeanPort();
        Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(sfPort);
        List<Interceptor<? extends Message>> ics = client.getBus().getOutInterceptors();

        for (Interceptor ic: ics) {
            if (ic instanceof LoggingOutInterceptor) {
                LoggingOutInterceptor out = (LoggingOutInterceptor) ic;
                out.setPrettyLogging(true);
                out.setLimit(1024 * 1024 *1024);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below mentioned annotations with your *web service*.

```
@InInterceptors(interceptors = "org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor")
@OutInterceptors(interceptors = "org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor")
@InFaultInterceptors(interceptors = "org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor")
@OutFaultInterceptors(interceptors = "org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor")
@Logging(pretty = true)
```